# How to get model-world matrix from position,rotation and scale of an object?

Tags: math, matrix, graphics, 3d

I want to get model-world matrix from my transform.

```
struct Transform{
    vec3 position
    vec3 scale
    Quaternion rotation
}
```

the position is in world space.

I know that I can get model-world matrix by this

```
ModelMatrix = Translation * Rotation * Scale
```

But I am not sure how to get translation matrix from position.

Comment: Do you want the model-world matrix or the translation? Title says one thing and question says another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh!I misunderstand the meaning of the order of T-R-S matrices multiplication. At first I thought that Translation would happened in a rotated coordinate system because we do rotation before translation. But in fact,if you really do matrix multiplication,you will find that it still translated in the original coordinate system by the T-R order. So you can just use position to build translation matrix despite rotation.

And if you use the R-T order, then translation will be happened in a rotated coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an Identity matrix and translate it to a certain position.

```
glm::mat4 positionMatrix = glm::mat4(); // create an identity matrix;
positionMatrix = glm::translate(positionMatrix, position); //position is a vec3
```